# How does map method work on string type?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have been browsing through `Alamofire` source code, and there's a code snippet I could not understand how and why it works.

```
if var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), !parameters.isEmpty {
    let percentEncodedQuery = (urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery.map { $0 + "&" } ?? "") + query(parameters)
    urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery = percentEncodedQuery
    urlRequest.url = urlComponents.url
}
```

It's the `urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery.map { $0 + "&" } ?? "")` that I don't understand how it works and why this is needed.

I then wrote my snippet:

```
import Foundation

let a: String = "hello world"

a.map { $0 + "&" } //error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character' and 'String'

print(a)
```

But it gives error on the `map` method.

Why isn't this work and what is the purpose of `urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery.map { $0 + "&" } ?? "")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a `map` over `String`, it's a `map` over `String?` (`Optional<String>`). A whole different method.

See [Optional.map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map)

> Evaluates the given closure when this Optional instance is not nil, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.

Basically, the code could be rewritten to:

```
(urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery?.appending("&") ?? "") + query(parameters)
```